# Dynamically applied texture to GameObject using GUI button

Tags: unity, textures, materials

In a scene I have multiple different GameObjects (almost 30 kinds) with parent child relationships. At run time (by using a GUI button) I want to change the texture of each clicked GameObject. As the user clicks specific GameObjects, a GUI with a multiple texture button will appear. By clicking on the button, that specific texture will be applied.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Do I need to apply a script to every object?

I have tried to apply a script with some specific code; it's working but not regularly and correctly.  Additionally, I want different texture options for each kind of GameObject.

Comment: The thing to be careful of is that while you can directly modify a material's main texture (among other properties) doing so causes that material to be cloned as a new instance. Unique material instances (which includes two clones that are identical, but separate references) cannot be batched which leads to more draw calls and lower performance. You'd be better off having your gui-object create the clone and instance properties and apply it to the `mesh.material` field of each object clicked on so that they all share the same material instance (and then reuse these materials as best possible).

Comment: "I have tried to apply a script with some specific code; it's working but not regularly and correctly." without seeing this code and with no description of what specifically is not working correctly it doesn't look like there's enough information here to determine the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If this should be a general possibility to change textures of objects dynamically, then I don't suggest to use a script on each object.

Consider building your own component, which loads a texture and checks every draw to see if it has to change the texture.

If you only have a few objects, about 1-10 in your scene, it's totally ok if you want a quick and dirty solution to apply a script to every object.

Having a script on each object will not affect performance dramatically. But it is not the a very practical use of a script. A script is supposed to define features, skills and movement which you want to apply to few objects, so that behave differently from the others. For general purposes you should use components or even hard code it in your routines, and for special cases you use a script.